# JPA getReferenceById is making sn SQL select query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Spring data JPA's `getReferenceById` is supposed to create "empty" instance without making the db request, according to the docs, but in my case it seems to make the db request anyway, am I doing something wrong?

Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class UserEntity(
    @CreationTimestamp
    val createdAtDatetime: String = "",

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int = 0,

    @Column(unique = true)
    val email: String = "",

    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    val password: String = "",

    @Column
    val role: UserRole = UserRole.WATCHER
)
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
interface UserJpaRepository : JpaRepository<UserEntity, Int>
```

Service:

```
@Service
class UserService(private val userJpaRepository: UserJpaRepository) {

    fun getAuthenticatedUser(): UserEntity? {
        val userId = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal as Int
        return userJpaRepository.findById(userId).get()
    }

    fun getAuthenticatedUserReference(): UserEntity? {
        val userId = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal as Int
        return userJpaRepository.getReferenceById(userId)
    }
}
```

SQL logs using `getAuthenticatedUser()`:

```
2024-03-19T15:04:42.220886Z  3598 Query set session transaction read only
2024-03-19T15:04:42.221767Z  3598 Query SET autocommit=0
2024-03-19T15:04:42.238068Z  3598 Query select ue1_0.id,ue1_0.created_at_datetime,ue1_0.email,ue1_0.password,ue1_0.role from users ue1_0 where ue1_0.id=1
2024-03-19T15:04:42.242639Z  3598 Query commit
2024-03-19T15:04:42.243286Z  3598 Query SET autocommit=1
2024-03-19T15:04:42.243905Z  3598 Query set session transaction read write
```

SQL logs using `getAuthenticatedUserReference()`:

```
2024-03-19T14:38:07.968035Z  3588 Query set session transaction read only
2024-03-19T14:38:07.968785Z  3588 Query SET autocommit=0
2024-03-19T14:38:07.985208Z  3588 Query select ue1_0.id,ue1_0.created_at_datetime,ue1_0.email,ue1_0.password,ue1_0.role from users ue1_0 where ue1_0.id=1
2024-03-19T14:38:07.990231Z  3588 Query commit
2024-03-19T14:38:07.990589Z  3588 Query SET autocommit=1
2024-03-19T14:38:07.991173Z  3588 Query set session transaction read write
```

They do the same thing.

I'm not accessing the user entity in anyway, just running those functions in a test.

I expect no SQL query being made in this scenario

Comment: When I deleted SecurityContexyHolder.getContext().authentication.principal and tested as same code, getReferenceById() did not generate additional queries.
Couldn't the cause be in SecurityContexyHolder.getContext().authentication.principal?
I need more information :)

Comment: @soonhankwon I've tried `userJpaRepository.getReferenceById(1)` and removing the context call, and it still makes the sql query